# Prove u2,u3,u4,.. is uniformly converge to u

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$\Delta(r)=\{z\in C; |z|<r\}$$

and $\;u\;$ be be a harmonic function on $\Delta(1)$ and continuous function on $\overline{\Delta(1)}$ .

Prove that:

$1.$ If $\;\displaystyle{u_n(z)=u\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)z\right)\;,\;\;n=2,3,4,..}\;$ , then $\;u_n\;$ is a harmonic function on $\Delta\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)$ and $u_2,u_3,u_4,..$ is uniformly convergent to $\;u\;$

$2.$ For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists harmonic polynomial $P(x,y)$ such that

$$\sup_{x+yi\in\overline{\Delta(1)}}{\mid u(x+yi)-P(x,y)\mid}<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog that $u$ is real-valued. $u$ is the real part of some analytic function $f$. $f((1-\frac 1 n)z)$ is analytic as well and $u_n$ is the real part of this. Thus $u_n$ is harmonic.

For the convergence of $u_n$ to $u$: $u$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{\Delta(1)}$. Since $$ |z-(1-\frac 1 n)z| = |z|\cdot |1-1+\frac 1 n| = \frac{|z|}{n} \leq \frac 1 n$$ 
the conclusion of part 1 follows.

A hint for part 2: You  can find $u_n$ which approximates $u$ with an error of at most $\frac \epsilon 2$. If you then can approximate $u_n$ with a harmonic polynomial $P$ with error at most $\frac \epsilon 2$ on $\overline{\Delta(1)}$ then $P$ will approximate $u$ with an error of at most $\epsilon$.

Further hint: You can approximate any $f((1-\frac 1 n)z)$ as closely as you want by a Taylor polynomial.

Comment: Could you tell me what properties should I use to find an approximation harmonic polynomial here?